# grep multiple lines from a text file

Tags: files, grep, text

Does anybody know how to grep multiple lines from a text file? I googled many results, but still not fully working.

Text file example:

```
x
x
x
---
start
a
b
c
d
---
x
x
x
```

And I want to get only this from the file:

```
---
start
a
b
c
d
---
```

It can be shorter (a b) or longer (a b c d e f g), but always starting with:

```
---
start
```

and ending with:

```
---
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this Linux or, if not, can you use GNU `grep`?

Comment: Do you have other sections that start with `---` but that does not continue with a line saying `start`?  Will your sections ever _overlap_ (share `---` lines)?

Comment: Yes it's Linux RH8 and some lines have a blank line between --- and start, but the rest is same

Comment: You should include a `-` in the "start" block in your example (e.g. change `b` to `b-k`) or you're likely to get solutions that'll fail given that input. Also be sure to test cases where there's a `start` that isn't preceded by `---` and where `---\nstart` exists but no `---` afterwards, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-z` option of `grep`:

> -z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline

```bsh
$ grep -zo -- '---.start[^-]*---' file
---
start
a
b
c
d
---
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that in your text, as shown in the example, there are no "trick" sections where lines `---` are always followed by `start`, you can reduce section heading to `---`, and use :

```
sed -n '/---/,//p' text
```

---

If you are not sure about the above statement :

```
sed -n '/---/{n;/start/{:a H;n;/---/!ba;x;G;s/^/---/p;s/.*/\n---/;D}}' test


sed : /bin/sed executable
-n : sed option to avoid auto line printing
/---/ : Match a pattern of 3 "-"
n: Get the next line of input
/start/: Match a line "start"
:a : Build a label called "a" (For the loop)
H: Happend the line to the HOLD space (Save it)
n: Get the next line
/---/!: Test if the current line **is not** equal to: "---"
ba: Jump to the label 'a' if the test succede
x: Swap the Hold space and the Pattern space.
G: Get the line from the Hold space and append it to the Pattern space
s/^/---/p: Append to the start of the string a sequence of "---" and print the line
s/.*/\n---/: Replace the current line with a new line and an : "---"
D: Delete character in the current line (Pattern space) up to the  first new line character and start the next cycle with the remaining line
```

---

`awk` in paragraph mode :

```
awk -v h="---" -v h2="start" '                     
    f == 2
    $0 == h {f=1}
    f == 1 && h2 == $0 {print h;print;f++}
' test
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by @schrodigerscatcuriosity,
you can do like

```
grep -zoP -- '(?s)\n---\nstart\n.*?\n---\n' file
```

`-P` for PCRE extension and `(?s)` fot `PCRE_DOTALL`

And for the optional blank lines between `---` and `start` you mentioned,

```
grep -zoP -- '(?s)\n---\n[\n\s]*start\n.*?\n---\n' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed
`sed -n '/^---$/{N;/---\nstart/{:loop;p;n;/^---$/{p;d};b loop};D;}' txtfile` 
If not close the section with --- => also print.... :(

Correct version:
`sed -n '/^---$/{N;/---\nstart/{:loop;N;/\n---$/{p;d};b loop};D;}' txtfile`

Txtfile:

```
x
x
x
---
---
start
a
b
c
d
---
x
x
x
---
start
a-
b
c
d
--
---
DDD
```

Output:

```
start
a
b
c
d
---
---
start
a-
b
c
d
--
---
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT and assuming `---\n` only appears in the input as a record separator (e.g. you can't have something like `b---\n` mid-record):

```
$ awk -v RS='---\n' -v ORS= '/^start/ && RT{print RT $0 RT}' file
---
start
a
b
c
d
---
```